# Windows tool to recursively download website preserving Unicode filenames

Tags: windows, download-manager, unicode, filenames

Normally I use [GNU wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget) to grab websites recursively.

But I want to fetch some websites with lots of Unicode URLs for various languages and I'd like to keep the Unicode in the filenames. ([Here's an example.](https://incubator.wikimedia.org/wiki/Wp/nod))

wget has commandline switches `--local-encoding` and `--remote-encoding` but they don't seem to support Windows' native filesystem encoding, UTF-16. I think this is because wget is designed for *nix which never has UTF-16 as a system encoding for filenames and Windows ports of wget are not official.

Is there another tool that can do this job under Windows and keep the files using correct Unicode?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **HTTrack Website Copier** for this.

You can download it from [This link](https://www.httrack.com/page/2/).

Comment: This post doesn't provide enough content to count as an answer, Sandeep (please see our [answer guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) for details). Be welcome to [edit] your post according to the guidelines and "ping" me when done (e.g. flag it or reference me in a comment as "@Izzy"), and I'll happily undelete it.

Comment: I did run HTTrack on the website whose link I gave as an example. The resulting filenames were not in the same correct Unicode as used in the site's URLs (IRIs).